# ng-repeat functionality for single object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This might sound like a weird question (sorry, new to Angular), but I need the functionality of an ng-repeat but I only need to bind to a single item. I am currently using a repeater but filtering the array down to one item like this...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue | filter: {fieldName:'design'}">
    <div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, height: 100 }"></div>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly, but I can't help thinking I shouldn't be using a repeater here as I'm only binding one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there a chance your filter will ever cause more than one item to be valid?`

If yes, then what you are doing is absolutely correct.

If no, then what you have done isn't necessarily wrong, as you are still acting on a collection.

`Will the filtered item will ever be different? In what circumstances does it change?`

If it never changes, then you should really be filtering the data in your controller and simply having something like `$scope.filteredItem` available to the view.

Comment: There will only ever be one match for the filter as I am removing duplicates. The Uploader is a directive created by somebody else and it has to use an array because there are lots of items even though I'm only interested in one with a particular "fieldName", I think I understand what you mean by filtering on the controller so I'll see if I can work that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
{{(uploader.queue | filter:{fieldName: 'design'})[0].file}}
```

Filter returns an array.  So we take the returned array, and then get the file property from the first entry (since you only want the first).

If the file binding is one-way ("@") as I suspect then you can do this:

```
<div ng-thumb="{file: {{(uploader.queue | filter:{fieldName:'design')[0].file}}, height: 100}"></ng-thumb>
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdTzf/2/)

Comment: Could I then do that inside the ng-thumb attribute?

Comment: Updated with an example.  Whether, or not, you need the double curlys depends on how ng-thumb binds to that attribute.

Comment: This does not fail gracefully when there is no such element in the queue, unlike the original solution included in the question.